# LabVIEW to .csv: Data in Header Line

Tags: csv, labview

I am working on an assignment to become familiar with NI LabVIEW. The assignment uses a pre-built VI and requires adjustments to accomplish a set of tasks. The pre-built VI is wired as follows:

[image: block diagram excerpt]

There is another Write to Text File function inside the loop with the %f format and , delimiter.
When opening the .csv file, the first line of data is on the same row as the headings put in through the Write to Text File function in the image. Is there a way to move the data start to the next row without changing the setup blocks?

I have tried the /r and /r/n new line delimiters, but that just adds them as text without solving the problem. A double comma just gives a blank cell between the last header and the data.

Comment: it wouldn't be `/r`, `/n` or `/r/n` because backslash escapes use `\ ` - so it might be `\r\n` for example.  But that may not work either - according to https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/new-line-in-text-files/td-p/140915 "Send an End of line character to the file. You can find an End of line constant in the string pallette."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [Write to Text File](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview-api-ref/page/functions/write-to-text-file.html) function writes *a string or an array of strings as lines* to a file. If you wire an array of strings to its input it writes each string as a separate line, separated with the the appropriate end-of-line character(s), but if you give it a single string it doesn't add the end-of-line.

I'm not sure which parts of this code you are supposed or not supposed to modify, but if we keep the same Write to Text function there are three ways you can get it to add a line ending:

- build your string into a single-element string array, then Write to Text will add the end-of-line characters
- use a **Concatenate Strings** function to append an **End of Line** constant to your string
- simply press return at the end of the text in your string constant.

[image: VI Snippet of the three examples]

The third one is the easiest to do!

To use escape codes like `\n` in your string constant, you need to right-click on it and select **'\' Codes Display** instead of **Normal Display**. If you do this after typing a return, the new line in your string constant should change to the end-of-line characters `\r\n` (if you're on Windows).